# XxX is not recognized as a valid type

Tags: java

I have this code :

```
List<NumericConfig> results = null;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
results = query.getResultList(); // query is JPA named query
```

But I receive this error :

> results is not recognized as a valid type

but this code works :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<NumericConfig> results = query.getResultList(); // query is JPA named query
```

Why my first code doesn't work please ?

Comment: is it in any method? i doubt. if no, it is as expected.

Comment: Don't nail me on it, but doesn't there need to be a `;` after `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Nope, it's correct that way.

Comment: @ay89 : it is in method body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotations like

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

can only be applied to packages, classes, class members (including `enum` value), or variable declarations.  They can't apply to arbitrary statements.

[Section 9.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.7) says

> Annotations may be used as modifiers in any declaration, whether package (§7.4), class (§8), interface, field (§8.3, §9.3), method (§8.4, §9.4), parameter, constructor (§8.8), or local variable (§14.4).

Since this appears inside a method body, the compiler has ruled out (package,class,member) declarations and so expects a variable declaration after it.  Variable declarations start with a type, so it interprets `results` as a type name and then realizes it's not, and complains about that, before realizing that `= query...` is not a valid variable name and initializer.

---

I think

```
List<NumericConfig> results
```

should probably be

```
List<? extends NumericConfig> results
```

since you probably don't know the exact implementation type used by the query, and can't validly add to a result list anyway.

---

I wouldn't add the annotation to the whole method because that might suppress other unchecked assignments that you (or a later code maintainer) are not sure are safe.

You can split the assignment in two

```
// This is type-safe because query is known to be a JPA named query.
// We use ? extends because query may be a more specific concrete type,
// and because we cannot add to the list owned by query.
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<? extends NumericConfig> resultListTyped = query.getResultList();
results = resultListTyped;
```

or, per my preference, you can attach the annotation to a static method

```
results = unpackResultList(query, NumericConfig.class);
```

and elsewhere

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T>
List<? extends T> unpackResultList(Query query, Class<T> resultType) {
  List<T> results = query.getResultList();
  // A quick and dirty sanity check of just the first value.
  assert results.isEmpty() || resultType.isInstance(results.get(0));
  return results;
}
```

This latter option has the benefit of also working on Java 5.

Comment: Did not know that this annotation must not be applied to arbitrary statements, thanks for this information. But how to deal with the "expression of type list needs unchecked conversion" if I delete this annotation ? May I put this annotation surrounded the method instead ? It's work when I'm doing this

Comment: @OlivierJ., please see my edits where I offer options for solving your immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations